# How to Custom Heads-up notification layout?

Tags: android, notifications

In my project, need change heads-up notification layout.

I have custom two `remoteView`, one for `Notification.contentView`, one for `Notification.bigContentView` and its succeed.

When I want to use `Notification.Builder.addAction` to add click button, it will use system layout not mine.

I changed another way, I custom layout & click button in my own layout, but it only show 64dp height.

```
    Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(NotificationDemo.this);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationDemo.this, 1, new Intent(NotificationDemo.this, MainActivity.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
nb.setFullScreenIntent(pi, true);
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);

//nb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), pi);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_demo);
RemoteViews bigcontentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_demo_bigg);
Notification mNo = nb.build();
mNo.bigContentView = bigcontentView;
mNo.contentView = contentView;
nm.notify(10000, mNo);
```

Second way:

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Notification.Builder(NotificationDemo.this);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(NotificationDemo.this, 1, new Intent(NotificationDemo.this, MainActivity.class), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
nb.setFullScreenIntent(pi, true);
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);

nb.addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), pi);
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_demo);
RemoteViews bigcontentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_demo_bigg);
Notification mNo = nb.build();
mNo.bigContentView = bigcontentView;
mNo.contentView = contentView;
nm.notify(10000, mNo);
```

Third way, I add actionbutton in layout.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you have tried or add a code snippet which does not work?

Comment: also can teach me how to custom heads-up layout with action button. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lollipop the notification has a new field named headsupContentView. use your custom remoteview, set to headsupContentView. it can be change.

Comment: When I use setCustomHeadsUpContentView the head-up notification does not appear, do you know why?