# Android: Create "Head-up" Notification Programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working on the notification and I want to have a "head-up" notification (Highlighted in Purple) similar to "Cal" app, which is shown in the picture below.
The app called this notification as "Head-up" notification, but I don't know if this is the correct name or not. It would be great if anyone would share how to create this feature programmatically on Android. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You can add a RelativeLayout with a Canvas anywhere on the screen... What have you tried to implement the feature?

Comment: Do you have any examples to show me? 
For this "head-up" notification, when you click on the box, it will launch the app and go to the event detail page. It is more than a layout on the screen. For the normal notification, we still have the notification manager to handle it, i just want to know the official name for this type of ui. If i know the name, then i will try to look for the way to create it.

Comment: I don't have examples or a name. That image is a custom widget on the home screen. All Views in Android essentially draw themselves within a rectangle. All you have to do is create a new `Canvas` or `View` object and draw on it after making it visible in the parent layout

Answer (score 1):

According to [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up), you are required to set a vibrate or ringtone to make Heads-up work. However, here's a quick hack that doesn't require VIBRATE permission to produce a head-up notification:

```
notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);
```

**To create custom layout for heads up notification, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167444/how-to-custom-heads-up-notification-layout-thank-you) link**.
In lollipop the notification has a new field named headsupContentView. use your custom remoteview, set to headsupContentView(). it can be change.

Don't abuse heads-up notification. See [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/notifications.html#notifications-guidelines) for when to use heads-up notification:

> MAX: For critical and urgent notifications that alert the user to a condition that is time-critical or needs to be resolved before they can continue with a particular task.
>
> HIGH: Primarily for important communication, such as messages or chat events with content that is particularly interesting for the user. High-priority notifications trigger the heads-up notification display.

More on this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451893/heads-up-notification-android-lollipop)