# How to show notification on system window in android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-notifications

I want to show custom dialog as shown in image. The dialog must be center aligned. Which permission are needed, both in manifest and programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Top notification window in android is called **Heads-up notification**,

your question has been asked here(In order to use notification heads up):

[How to Custom Heads-up notification layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30167444/9391162)

and also you can check this link in order to use notifications pop up properly in different kinds of Android API:

[android show notification with a popup on top of any application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29949501/9391162)

But you can simply show your dialog through your service(For example your FCM service):

[Show a Dialog when Firebase Notification is received and App is in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44678013/9391162)

Comment: How will I align this Custom Heads Up notification in center?

Comment: Oh ha!
If you don't want to use heads-up notification, you can just simply show your dialog through your (For example) FCM service, when notification received, you just create an intent and show your dialog.
You can search about showing a dialog via Service.